# Trying to assign groups in R, but it is filling in NA values and missing others that belong in the group

Tags: r, variables, missing-data

So I have a dataset in R (Framingham Heart Study data), and I am trying to assign BMI groups "underweight," "normal," "overweight," and "obese."

It has over 11,000 observations and 38 variables/columns, so it would be kind of hard to post some of the data here (I hope this won't be too much trouble to answer without it).

The dataset is called frm and I am trying to subset in the following way:

```
frm$BMIGRP <- NA  #Creating new variable (this part works and creates a BMIGRP column with all NA values)
frm$BMIGRP[which(as.numeric(frm$BMI) < 18.5)] <- "underweight"
```

However, there are NA values in the data set BMI variable (indicated with a ".", which I have also tried changing to NA).

When I try to subset this way for each group, it is assigning only some of the underweight values to "underweight" and is assigning a lot of NA / "." values to underweight as well. It then tells me there are only 10 "normal" weight subjects and about 11000 in the obese category which is just not true because I can view the data set.

If done correctly, this should create the four groups with several hundred to several thousand observations in each category. But I am only getting 10 normal, 71 underweight, and ~11,000 obese.

I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong with this or if there is a different way I can create a new variable and assign it in the same kind of way. Any help is very much appreciated.

I should also mention that this is the code that my professor gave us as an example in our lab session, and I am basically copying and pasting it with the appropriate replacements for my data set.

This is my first question on this website so I apologize if it is incomplete or if I need to give more information. Thanks!

Comment: Check the class of the BMI column, class(frm$BMI). It should be numeric.

Comment: Yep it was not numeric, it was char for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your code, it seems the column is not numeric.

This should work:

```
frm$BMI <- as.numeric(frm$BMI)
frm$BMIGRP[frm$BMI < 18.5] <- "underweight"
```

Comment: I tried reimporting the data set using the import data set button and I did see that the column was not numeric (it was char somehow?) and I changed it to numeric. After that, I used your code and it worked! I think you meant for it to say frm$BMIGRP[frm$BMI < 18.5] so I tried that instead. Thanks!

Comment: Correct that is what I meant. Glad it fixed it for you. Updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Like @leeum said. Check that `BMI` is numeric. If you want to make a new category column based on the `BMI`, look at `case_when` from `dplyr`. So maybe this is what you wanted:

```
library(dplyr)

frm <- frm %>% 
  mutate(BMI = as.numeric(BMI)) %>%
  mutate(BMIGRP = case_when(
    BMI < 18.5 ~ 'underweight',
    between(BMI, 18.5, 24.9)  ~ 'healthy weight',
    between(BMI, 25, 29.9) ~ 'overweight',
    BMI > 30 ~ 'obese')
  )
```

The `mutate(BMIGRP = as.numeric(BMIGRP))` converts the `BMIGRP` column to numeric. Then the `mutate(BMIGRP = case_when(...)` will create a new column called `BMIGRP` and assign 'underweight', 'healthy weight', 'overweight' or 'obese' based on the `BMI`. If the argument doesn't apply, an `NA` will be assigned.